# Loading assets with FObjectFinder

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am working FPS example code included in the engine. I am trying to load a new skeletal mesh that I added in to the content browser and assign to the my SkeletalMesh Component based on certain conditions.

This is the code I am trying to use for loading the Skeletal Mesh, but seemingly it cannot load from this path, as it is unable to fine the asset:

```
 ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<USkeletalMesh> newAsset(TEXT("SkeletalMesh'/Content/FirstPerson/FPWeapon/Mesh/SK_FPGun.uasset'"));
```

Is there anything wrong in the way the path is given? It is just a simple load of an asset

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have your *path* wrong. It should be `"SkeletalMesh'/Game/FirstPerson/FPWeapon/Mesh/SK_FPGun.uasset'"`. (Assuming that you have folder named `FirstPerson` in a `Content` folder).

The safest way to get asset's reference is by **Right mouse click** on asset and then click on **Copy reference**. This way you can always get correct path to use in `FObjectFinder`.